# Continuous heart rate monitor

Tags: target-heart-rate, heart-rate-monitor

I'd like to monitor my heartrate throughout the day, and do some analysis/visualisation of the data myself. As such, I'm hoping to find something that meets the following requirements:

Must-have:

- Not the "contact" version where you have to manually touch the watch to take a reading
- Stores data and exports data to a text format, or a third party API that can do this

Nice-to-have:

- Strapless
- Rechargable

Has anyone else had experience with solutions for this sort of experiment?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic, according to the [FAQ].

Answer (score 3):

I've had my eye on the [Basis B1](https://mybasis.com/) for a while, and they seem to be ready to launch in spring 2012.

Comment: From their FAQ:
Basis does not measure minute-by-minute for specific athletic heart rate training or medical uses.

Comment: Saw that too... think I'll wait and see what the early adopters say

Comment: And now they're not responding to my request to remove me from the backorder list.

Answer (score 2):

[Epulse 2](http://www.heartratemonitorsusa.com/e-pulse.html)

Strapless, rechargeable, continuous heart rate monitor. Don't know if it stores the data for you though.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has data export

Answer (score 2):

[Timex Ironman Race Trainer Pro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004M7H7O4) 
lets you sync with your computer and is compatable with either a PC or a Mac.  I don't know if it meets your needs otherwise.  It does have a strap and I don't know if you can recharge it.

Answer (score 2):

[Alpha](http://alphaheartrate.com/) is strapless.

It is not clear if it stored everything on the device, but technically it can beam continuously to a SmartPhone, and there seems to be some apps for it  (I am investigating)

Somebody edited in this:A review is [here](http://www.dcrainmaker.com/2012/12/a-day-of-continuous-heart-rate-monitoring.html)

The review actually describes one day of continuous recording with a smartphone app (Bluetooth).  Seems it worked well, except for one crash (Probably the fault of the app).

Think we can conclude that contiguous recording on the device itself does not work.
Also there is some mention of charging (One of the points of the question)