# What runner's heart rate monitoring gadgets let a user to download his heart rate history to a PC?

Tags: running, heart-rate-monitor, heart-rate

I am a science&tech "geek" (I like to study things myself, using my PC in advanced ways like programming my own analytic solutions) and I like to run. So I am willing to purchase a gadget (like a watch or so) that would not only provide me with live data based on my heart rate when I run, but also let me download the heart rate dynamics (I mean the way like an ECG) data as "time series" to my PC so that I'd be able to analyze it myself.

Can you recommend any particular models? I don't know any for sure. Many are USB-enabled and can transfer some data to a PC but I couldn't find information about what exactly do they transfer and I am not sure if they can record and give me the heart rate history.

Other features are not really important. The only feature I actually want is what I have described, all the others would be just pleasant "bonuses".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a shopping recommendation.

Comment: Where can I get this information from then, @Informaficker?

Comment: I think this is a question better suited for [chat]. If the chat can't help you, a forum or a similar platform should be better to address these types of question. If you already have a specific model in mind but are not sure, try not to look only at official information but have a look at reviews, too. (or give it a shot and search directly how to export data from $device).

Comment: A [similar question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/5030/3941) has been closed before, but might have some information.